# Do Facebook or its third-party partners use my photos in ads?

Tags: security, social-media

There's a current scare going around FB that now that it wants to make some actual money, they'll start using profile pics and other things uploaded to facebook in advertisements.

Here is an example of the messages that get sent around:

> On Friday, FACEBOOK will start using your photos in ads that will appear on the profile of your contacts. It is legal and was mentioned to you when you open an account. To prevent this do the following: Home -> Account Settings -> Facebook Adverts -> Adverts shown by third parties -> Edit third party advert settings, then choose "No one" in the list and save the changes. Copy this and paste in your profile.

I guess it won't hurt to have this confirmed or debunked here.

Comment: This is inferring that they will be able to take your facebook photos outside of facebook to market their product.  This is not the claim and but why it looks bad.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Yes, they do.

From [Facebook's privacy page for ads](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=ads):

> Everyone wants to know what their friends like. That's why we pair ads and friends—an easy way to find products and services you're interested in, based on what your friends share and like. Learn more about social ads.
>
> Here are the facts:
>
> Social ads show an advertiser's message alongside actions you have taken, such as liking a Page
>
> - Your privacy settings apply to social ads
> - We don't sell your information to advertisers
> - Only confirmed friends can see your actions alongside an ad
> - **If a photo is used, it is your profile photo and not from your photo albums**

You can turn it off in [your settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=ads).

Comment: Bravo on the answer short, concise answer.

Comment: Facebook are also currently defending a lawsuit from individuals who have had their images used in this way.

Comment: @Rory: Interesting. Got a link?

Comment: Facebook accused of 'wanton' use of Canadian woman's pics - http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/04/03/facebook_canada_class_action_suit/

Comment: sounds like a frivolous lawsuit, as under the TOS the woman agreed on she gave FB the right to do that.

Comment: @jwenting: sounds like someone wants to make some easy cash to me...

Comment: @jwenting probably; at the same time the limits of what a company can get away with putting in the TOS tends to be defined by the courts as much as by legislatures.

Comment: @DanNeely true, but a clause that they can use content you created for marketing or broadcasting is standard for websites. Without it they could be sued for just showing the content to their other users (or even to you) as that would constitute broadcasting and if the user weren't already a customer could be construed as marketing.